# How to avoid display error when filtering > 0 in the middle of the map

Tags: reactjs

I have a state "inventory", it stores item, price, qty, remark
when display using 
this.state.inventory.filter(q => q.qty > 0).map
everything shows fine only if there's no 0 within

Googled and stackoverflowed, can't find any way to solve this..
new to ReactJS

```js
{this.state.inventory.filter(q => q.orderQty > 0).map((val,ind) => (
    <tr key={ind}>
        <td>{ind}.{this.state.inventory[ind].item}</td>
        <td>{(this.state.inventory[ind].price).toLocaleString()}</td>
        <td>{(this.state.inventory[ind].orderQty).toLocaleString()}</td>
       <td>{(this.state.inventory[ind].orderQty * this.state.inventory[ind].price).toLocaleString()}</td>
        <td>{this.state.inventory[ind].orderRem}</td>
        <td><button onClick={(e) => { this.handleDeleteRow(e,ind); }}>DEL</button></td>
    </tr>
))
}
```

My question is, when looping inside the map, inventory[ind].orderQty === 0, the rest of the map becomes incorrect. how do I skip when inventory[ind].orderQty === 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because you are using Index. using index is always a bad option. use the object directly instead "val"

```
{
this.state.inventory.filter(q => q.orderQty > 0).length>0?
this.state.inventory.filter(q => q.orderQty > 0).map((val,ind) => (
    <tr key={ind}>
        <td>{ind}.{val.item}</td>
        <td>{(val.price).toLocaleString()}</td>
        <td>{(val.orderQty).toLocaleString()}</td>
       <td>{(val.orderQty * val.price).toLocaleString()}</td>
        <td>{val.orderRem}</td>
        <td><button onClick={(e) => { this.handleDeleteRow(e,ind); }}>DEL</button></td>
    </tr>
)):""
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, really appreciated! and apologizing for not stating clear enough.. My question is when inventory[ind].orderQty === 0, the rest of the map becomes incorrect. how do I check/filter within the map?

Comment: what do you mean by incorrect? according to your code it only gets those objects from the array which have quantity more than zero. so inside the loop you can never get item whose qty is equal to zero

Comment: please check out: (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdywKE)
for the num column, please enter 1,2,3,4 into four inputs and press submit
then change 3 to 0, which will displayed strangely like (https://imgur.com/a/OKxzxwI)
(but console.log seems fine ...)
sorry and thank for spending time on my noob questions

Comment: also try to implement delete function without using index. it might problems later